# Download image direct from url

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have some URL to an image on the web. Let's say the URL is `http://www.gearheadwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Mercedes-Benz-S-Class-4.jpg`

Now, when a user press the download button, the image should be downloaded.

I've tried this:

```
window.location.href = Link;
```

But sometimes it just opens the image on the browser and sometimes it is downloaded as I wanted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What language are you using? You tagged this question `car` which is a subset of `r` which is generally used for statistical computing, not web development.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [HTML5 `download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) on anchors :

```
<a href="http://www.gearheadwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Mercedes-Benz-S-Class-4.jpg" download="http://www.gearheadwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Mercedes-Benz-S-Class-4.jpg">
   <img src="http://www.gearheadwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Mercedes-Benz-S-Class-4.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: The download attribute isn't supported in IE & Safari please note. http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass appropriate headers in order to allow user to download the file. If you just provide the file link in the url the browsers interpret it differently. They may first try to open the file in the browser, if it fails the file will be prompt as force-download.

If you are using PHP, the headers in download script is something like:

```
 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
```

The full tutorial can be found here: [www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/04/file-download-script-in-php-php.html](http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/04/file-download-script-in-php-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set Content-Disposition header field, as suggested by http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html, if you want the image should not be handled natively by browser. If you use PHP, may be this link would help, http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=39943

Only issue with this, you can't directly make apache serve you this file, as a normal static resource, or I don't know the way to do this Apache :)